# Scroll NSScrollView contents to specific point, programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsscrollview

OK, this thing has been bugging me for quite some time.

I've got an `NSScrollView` (X= 258, Y= 322, W=516, H=653)
with a view in it (X= -283, Y= -215, W= 1800 H= 1800), and I'm desperately trying to make it scroll to the **top-left corner**.

I've tried `[[_previewScrollView contentView] scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0,0)];` but it didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The put the inner view at X = 0, Y = 0, or do a `scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(-283, -215)`. The subview needs a relative coordinate.

Also, are you sure your IBOutlet to scrollview is not nil?

Comment: Hmmm... Sorry, this did nothing at all.

Comment: Well if 'nothing helps', and 'it didn't work' is all you come up with, you're on your own.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I know my comments may not seem that... "helpful". However, I still do not know what to say, since I'm getting zero error messages. And I most definitely cannot describe what the suggestions' result is. Yours did nothing at all - no effect whatsoever. While @RolandKeesom 's suggestion *did* move the scrollview content, but I still can't understand *how* it moved it... :S

Comment: As for the `IBOutlet` to the scrollView not being `nil`, it's already been perfectly `NSLog`ged - so that's not the issue...

Comment: Can you get this tutorial working? http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the correct contentSize

```
[_previewScrollView.documentView setFrame: NSMakeRect(0,0,1800, 1800)];
```

The code I use to scroll to top:

```
[_previewScrollView.contentView scrollToPoint:NSMakePoint(0, ((NSView*)_previewScrollView.documentView).frame.size.height - _previewScrollView.contentSize.height)];
```

Comment: Hmmm, not working... This gives out an `-[NSScrollView setContentSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ` error...

Comment: Still nothing. I don't know what's going on... :S

Comment: Its nt NSScrollView, it's a UIScrollView, and you need to send the message to an instance, not a class

Comment: The scrollbars are out of sync if you manually scroll the content view.